# Creating a shorthand annotation that is picked up by spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm trying to create a custom annotation in java with spring to speed up development. For example, if I have 10 @ComponentScans I want to add in multiple projects, I don't want to copy paste them everywhere. Instead, I want to create one annotation in a shared library that applies all 10 @Component scans when it's used. Think of how @RestController works:

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public @interface RestController {
    @AliasFor(
        annotation = Controller.class
    )
    String value() default "";
}
```

So by using @RestController, it's shorthand for applying the @Controller and @ResponseBody.

Now to get to my code:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@ComponentScan({"some.package1", "some.package2})
@Documented
public @interface EnableOverwatch {
}
```

and my main class/method:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOverwatch
public class Experiments {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Experiments.class, args);
    }

}
```

In this form, it doesn't do anything and spring complains at startup about unsatisfied dependencies since it doesn't know where to look for the classes (it just assumes the normal component scan under the current package). If I copy/paste the component scan from the annotation directly in the main class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"some.package1", "some.package2})
public class Experiments {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Experiments.class, args);
    }

}
```

all is well.

Why is spring not picking up my custom annotation and acting on it, but other annotations of the same type (like @RestController) work?

Thanks

---

later edit:

I got it to work by going with a different approach:

Create a configuration stereotype in the share library that contains the component scans:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("package1")
@ComponentScan("package2")
public class OverwatchConfiguration {

}
```

change the annotation to use @Import for that @Configuration class:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Import(OverwatchConfiguration.class)
@Documented
public @interface EnableOverwatch {
}
```

Now it is behaving as expected. Still would really appreciate an explanation why the first approach does not work and how does spring do the component scans.